# Wno-pointer-arith flag handled differently between different gcc versions

Tags: c, gcc-warning, gcc4.8, gcc4.9

I'm cross compiling a project for various architectures and OS. Two of them are Android with `arm-linux-androideabi-4.9` and Raspbian with `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc`(4.8.3).

My code has a dependency on the [Ne10](https://github.com/projectNe10/Ne10) project which does some arithmetic on void pointers.

I'm compiling with `-Wpedantic` and `-Wno-pointer-arith` for the two toolchains however, the Android one compiles fine but the Raspbian one still shows some warning about the void pointer arithmetic.

```
error: pointer of type 'void *' used in arithmetic [-Werror=pedantic]
```

I know the warning/error could be removed by removing `-Wpedantic` but that's not an option for me.

I am wondering if the issue could come from the difference between the version numbers but the doc of both are the same about the void arithmetic.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Alternate way: Fix the code to not use non-standard extension and submit patch.

Comment: In yor make file do not use `-Wpedantic` to compile `NE10`

Comment: @user694733 Thank you for your advice, I'm looking at it.

Comment: @P__J__ I am using CMake, this could be an option too, to just remove it for Ne10

Comment: I did some trial & error and it seems that `-Wno-pointer-arith` in combination with `-pedantic` only works well from 4.9.0 and beyond. Poke at the changes made in that version.

Comment: Thanks @Lundin, that confirms my thoughts about the issue being fixed between these two versions. If you want to post this as an answer, I'd be happy to mark it as solution for my post =)

Comment: @Damien I couldn't find any official source, the gcc change log is broad and quite poorly written. I guess we'd have to dig through the version control but that's too much work for me.